# Format JavaScript vscode code to be like java in eclipse

Tags: javascript, java, formatting, format, prettier

I have code formatted like this

```
   subRedirect() {

        let features = this.config.get('features')
        if (features !== null) {
            features.forEach(feature => {
                this.composeWith(require.resolve("../" + feature.type.toLowerCase()));

            })


        }

    }
```

but when editing and saving with prettier it will be like this

```
 subRedirect() {
    let features = this.config.get("features");
    if (features !== null) {
      features.forEach((feature) => {
        this.composeWith(require.resolve("../" + feature.type.toLowerCase()));
      });
    }
  }
```

is there a way or prettier config file to achieve the first code format

i tried some extensions on VScode but none working with JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set a prettier config that will add extra spaces into your code like that. Honestly, it's a bad habit to get into and you should avoid doing that. Line breaks should only be used where they are separating content logically. This would not pass the sniff-test for any code review. If you're asking about the trailing semicolon, then you can create a .prettierrc file and put this content into it:

```
{
  "semi": false,
}
```